# When is a quotient of an affine scheme by a group scheme action a uniform categorical quotient?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, rt.representation-theory

We work over a ring $k$ (not necessarily a field. Let $G$ be a group scheme acting on an affine scheme $X = \text{Spec }R$. This is a naive question - what are the properties satisfied by $X/G := \text{Spec }R^G$?

Mumford-Fogarty show in their book Geometric Invariant Theory (Theorem 1.1) that if $k$ is a field and $G$ is reductive, then this is a uniform categorical quotient (commutes with flat base change). Can these conditions be relaxed at all? Certainly this quotient will commute by base changing by a flat map $k\rightarrow k'$, though that is not enough to check uniformity.

In particularly interested in the case $k = \mathbb{Z}$, and $G$ a split reductive group over $\mathbb{Z}$. I'm also interested in examples where this can fail.

Comment: https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82714919.pdf.  perhaps this will be helpful to you